# HOW TO GET PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE AND AVAILABILITY?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, category-attribute, object-manager

I want to get the Product attribute using Object manager and check the availability of the product if its RTS  I have to assign that product to a category id.

Comment: object manager is not best practice for Magento. Same thing you can get without object manager as well.

Comment: Agreed but for testing purpose i am using object manager

Answer (score 0):

**Product Attribute**

You can get product attribute with below code -

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
$ressource = $product->getResource();
$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();

$ressource->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(),'attribute_code',$store->getId());
```

**Product Availability**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
) {
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}
// you can pass $product object to the function
public function getStockStatus($product)
{
    return $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
}
```

You can get all the stock details by

```
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
$stockData = $stockItem->getData();
$stockItem->getIsInStock();
```